# Can't detect language for the text "Notebook 9 Pro" given from pre_save signal. Django 2.1, Python 3.7

Tags: python, django, transliteration

I want to automatically create slug in admin with helping by `pre_save signal` (when filling in the model's  name), but I have next error: *Can't detect language for the text "Notebook 9 Pro" given.*

I know, that can make with `prepopulated_fields`, but i need method with pre_save signal. 
Thx.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail', kwargs={'product_slug': self.slug})

def pre_save_product_slug(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        slug = slugify(translit(str(instance.title), reversed=True))
        instance.slug = slug

pre_save.connect(pre_save_product_slug, sender=Product)
```

**Traceback**

```
/media/m0nte-cr1st0/43338d5a-aa90-411c-a6d7-96964c46e415/m0nte-cr1st0/programming/django_projects/djangoshop/ecomapp/models.py in pre_save_product_slug
        slug = slugify(translit(str(instance.title), reversed=True)) ...
▶ Local vars
/media/m0nte-cr1st0/43338d5a-aa90-411c-a6d7-96964c46e415/m0nte-cr1st0/programming/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/transliterate/utils.py in translit
        language_code = detect_language(value, fail_silently=False) ...
▶ Local vars
/media/m0nte-cr1st0/43338d5a-aa90-411c-a6d7-96964c46e415/m0nte-cr1st0/programming/django_projects/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/transliterate/utils.py in detect_language
            _("""Can't detect language for the text "%s" given.""") % text ...
▶ Local vars
```

I'm getting error if I'm input english chars. If I'm inputting russian chars , slug doesn't translating their to english.

I need a slug to form an url.

Comment: What is `translit` and why are you running your slug through it?

Comment: translit it is a method, which translates russian chars to english.
I'm getting error if I'm input english chars. If I'm inputting russian chars , slug doesn't translating their to english.

Comment: I need a slug to form an url

Comment: Try to add language as a second paramether to `translit` like this: `translit(str(instance.title), 'ru', reversed=True)` Works fine for me, I use 'transliterate` library.

Comment: @bloodwithmilk it's working, thnx)

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add language as a second parameter to `translit` function:

```
from transliterate import translit


def pre_save_product_slug(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        slug = slugify(translit(str(instance.title), 'ru', reversed=True))
        instance.slug = slug
```